# regarding returning 'null' in apex

Tags: apex

I have datatable consists of checkbox and materialno.
If materialno is '1' and checkbox checked it should return null.
if materialno '1' and '2' selected and checkbox checked for both it should redirect to opportunity page.

For me,null is coming if 1 is selected with checkbox but if I select both its not redirecting so please help me out.

```
for(Movie__c m: mp){ 
 PageReference pr = new PageReference('/'+opp_id);
 if (m.checked__c==true){ 
    if(m.material_id__c=='1')
    { 
         return null;
    } 
    return pr; 
 } 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please update this question with your code as well.

Comment: for(Movie__c m: mp){           PageReference pr = new PageReference('/'+opp_id);
        if (m.checked__c==true){
        if(m.material_id__c=='1'){
         return null;}
        if(m.material_id__c=='1' && m.material_id__c=='2' ){
         return pr;}
       
        }
     
        } I cant post original code so posting only portion of dummy code which works on the same condition of my original code.

Comment: @Gayathri Isn't it obvious that even if one of them is checked it will return null and wont process further? Also how can both the conditions be true `m.material_id__c=='1' && m.material_id__c=='2'` for the same record for you to return the pagereference?

Comment: I have 2 records ok...material 1 and material 2 if anyone is selected I should get alert saying select the other material and it should be on the same page until we select both the materials.if both selected no alerts and it should navigate to opportunity page. I cant handle it through client side as id's are dynamically generating so please suggest me what is the approach to this case?@aslam

Comment: so obviously that is not happening in your code. You do know how a for loop works right? You are trying to check the material_id__c field for the same record in your loop. Try to have some kind of counter or flag to identify it inside the loop and check the flag outside the loop and decide what to return.

Comment: @aslam...I cant use counter as I am checking my condition on object not on list.

Comment: can u explain whatever u said..i didn't get what to do? @ aslam

Comment: anyone suggest what needs to be done in this scenario?

Comment: It may help you to understand that the minute the code does a `return` call, it breaks the loop. So your loop will only ever iterate the one time and never check the second record.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, this might work for you.

```
Boolean flag1 = false;
Boolean flag2 = false;
PageReference pr = new PageReference('/'+opp_id);
for(Movie__c m: mp){ 

 if (m.checked__c==true){ 
    if(m.material_id__c=='1')
    { 
        flag1 = true;
    }
    else if(m.material_id__c=='2')
    {
        flag2= true;
    }
 } 
}

if(flag1 && flag2)
    return pr;
else
    return null;
```

Comment: If it helped you, please mark it as an answer @gayathri